# Centre 4 images with adaptive layout in iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9

Using iOS9's adaptive layout I would like to display 4 images in a row 
[x x x x], with all four images equally spaced and all four centered on screen.

I am using Xcode's Interface Builder to add constrains. I have added constrains to get an equal horizontal spacing of 15points between each image, but I want all 4 images to centre within in the frame regardless of screen size or orientation.

e.g.
Current View

```
[x x x x      ]
```

What I would like

```
[   x x x x   ]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the wonderful new UIStackView and center *that*. It contains your other views and you'll configure it to distribute them horizontally within itself as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a transparent (Clear) UIView object between images 2 and 3.
Make it's width 15points, with no horizontal space between it and the images.
Then centre this object.